# UITextView text is loosing font size when i set an Attribute on NSTextStorage with NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName

Tags: ios, objective-c, textkit

In my App i have a UItextView and its input view has accessory view with couple of buttons on it.

I am trying to change the text already being typed to underline text. Its working fine but its loosing the font and the font size after conversion.

Here's what i am doing:

```
NSRange selectedRange = [self.commentsTextView selectedRange];

            NSDictionary *currentAttributesDict = [self.commentsTextView.textStorage attributesAtIndex:selectedRange.location
                                                                            effectiveRange:nil];

            NSDictionary *dict;

            if ([currentAttributesDict objectForKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName] == nil ||
                [[currentAttributesDict objectForKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName] intValue] == 0) {

                dict = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]};

            }
            else{
                dict = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]};
            }

            [self.commentsTextView.textStorage beginEditing];
            [self.commentsTextView.textStorage setAttributes:dict range:selectedRange];
            [self.commentsTextView.textStorage endEditing];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the attributes for that range of text using a dictionary that only has a value for `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName`.

In your `if... else` structure, in addition to `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName` give `dict` the values that you want for the *font* and *font size*.

How did you previously set the *font* and *font size*?

From Apple's doc on `UITextView` the *Overview* section:

> In iOS 6 and later, this class supports multiple text styles through
>   use of the attributedText property. (Styled text is not supported in
>   earlier versions of iOS.) Setting a value for this property causes the
>   text view to use the style information provided in the attributed
>   string. You can still use the font, textColor, and textAlignment
>   properties to set style attributes, but those properties apply to all
>   of the text in the text view.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html

When you set the attributes for a specific range of text, it will overwrite any styles that previously existed in that range, using the new attributes only.

Comment: Got it. The attributes needed to be combined. Thanks